# Pick most recent duplicate in SQL when ID column is different

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, partition

Okay let's say I have data which looks like this:

```
 ID   GROUP                TIMESTAMP    col_OTHER    
001      AA  2021-04-02 15:02:33.319       mangos
002      BB  2021-04-01 05:56:35.334        kiwis
004      AA  2021-04-02 03:51:35.279      oranges
003      DD  2021-04-01 18:24:23.469      oranges
003      DD  2021-04-02 12:16:21.539      bananas
002      CC  2021-04-02 11:02:51.313       apples
```

So all I really want to do is manipulate this using SQL to provide a DF with the most recent date when there are multiple ID's.

Final product:

```
 ID   GROUP                TIMESTAMP    col_OTHER    
001      AA  2021-04-02 15:02:33.319       mangos
004      AA  2021-04-02 03:51:35.279      oranges
003      DD  2021-04-02 12:16:21.539      bananas
002      CC  2021-04-02 11:02:51.313       apples
```

My supervisor recommended I partition by ID and group and then select the max (timestamp) so we keep the latest group. But is the PARTITION() even necessary??? Maybe he wants to preserve a count of site users but also only select the ones as above.

Comment: apoligies, force of habit @akrun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use also the window function RANK()

The PARTITION defines the group of row that get the increasing numbers.

without it you would get a sequential number over **all++ rows, and could so not get only the first or second or which number you want

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `ID` VARCHAR(4),
>   `GROUP` VARCHAR(2),
>   `TIMESTAMP` TIMESTAMP,
>   `col_OTHER` VARCHAR(7)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`ID`, `GROUP`, `TIMESTAMP`, `col_OTHER`)
> VALUES
>   ('001', 'AA', '2021-04-02 15:02:33.319', 'mangos'),
>   ('002', 'BB', '2021-04-01 05:56:35.334', 'kiwis'),
>   ('004', 'AA', '2021-04-02 03:51:35.279', 'oranges'),
>   ('003', 'DD', '2021-04-01 18:24:23.469', 'oranges'),
>   ('003', 'DD', '2021-04-02 12:16:21.539', 'bananas'),
>   ('002', 'CC', '2021-04-02 11:02:51.313', 'apples');
> ```

> ```
> sELECT 
> `ID`, `GROUP`, `TIMESTAMP`, `col_OTHER`
> FROM ( SELECT *,
>          RANK() OVER (
>           PARTITION BY ID 
>           ORDER BY `TIMESTAMP` DESC) rnk
>   FROM table1) t1
>  WHERE rnk = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> ID  | GROUP | TIMESTAMP           | col_OTHER
> :-- | :---- | :------------------ | :--------
> 001 | AA    | 2021-04-02 15:02:33 | mangos   
> 002 | CC    | 2021-04-02 11:02:51 | apples   
> 003 | DD    | 2021-04-02 12:16:22 | bananas  
> 004 | AA    | 2021-04-02 03:51:35 | oranges
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cc9a469ce0c7eb9ecef4551ac7ee317d)*

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select *
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by id order by timestamp desc) as rn
  from t
) x
where rn = 1
```

Comment: what does it mean when u write x? how do you reference the original table?

Comment: I fixed the query (added the `from t` -- your table). `x` is just an alias for the table expression between parenthesis.